# The Hölder inequality for fractional order Sobolev seminorm?

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus

This question is post on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993560/the-minkowski-inequality-for-fractional-order) a week ago. I move it here to draw more attention.

Let $u\in C^\infty(\bar I)$ be given where $I=(0,1)$. Define
$$
t(\alpha):=\left(\int_I\int_I \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^\alpha}{|x-y|^{1+s\alpha}}\right)^{\frac1\alpha}
$$
where $1<\alpha<2$, $0<s<1$ is fixed. Note the $t(\alpha)$ above defines the fractional order sobolev seminorm. See [the Wikipedia article on "Sobolev space", section "Sobolev spaces with non-integer $k$"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_spaces_with_non-integer_k).

We know that for usual $L^p$ space, we have, for $p<q$, $\|u\|_{L^p(I)}\leq \|u\|_{L^q(I)}$ by using Hölder inequality. So I am wondering whether similar properties hold for sobolev fractional seminorm with non-integer $k$.

That is, I am wondering for $1<\alpha_1<\alpha_2<2$, do we have
$$
t(\alpha_1)\leq Ct(\alpha_2)
$$
hold, where $C$ is a constant does not depends on $u$. Just like what we usually have for $L^p$ norm. However, I tried to prove it by using Minkowski inequality or something like Hölder, but I can't do it… I think the domain $I=(0,1)$ would be important and I also tried to use Jensen inequality, but no lucky…

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: sorry, you are right, there was something wrong with that

Comment: The embedding properties mentioned in the wikipedia article should give something like this, though one probably has to replace $t(\alpha)$ by $\|u\|_{\alpha}+t(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question can be rephrased by asking whether one has a Hölder estimate
$$
  |u|_{W^{s, p}} \le C |u|_{W^{s, q}},
$$
when $p < q$ or whether $W^{s, q} \subset W^{s, p}$.

**There is no such embedding or inequality.**

For proofs of this fact you can have a look at the paper Mironescu, Sickel, [*A Sobolev non embedding*, Atti Accad. Naz. Lincei Rend. Lincei Mat. Appl. *26* (2015), no 3, 291—298](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01162231).

One way to see this is to take 
$$
  u(x) = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} c_j e^{i 2^j x},
$$
and to observe that 
$$
|u|_{W^{s, p}}^p \simeq \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} |2^{js} c_j|^p,
$$
and then choose suitably $c_j$.

Comment: I understand. Btw, would it make any difference if I restrict my $p$ and $q$ is a small interval? For example, if I assume that $1<p<q<1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ could be arbitrary small. Would this make any different?

Comment: No, in fact. The integral can be finite for some $q$ and infinite for every $p < q$. The only possibility is to decrease slightly the smoothness in the left-hand side of the inequality by taking a $W^{r, p}$ norm with $r <s$ and $q < p$.

Comment: I learned about this non-embedding result about a couple of years ago and I was quite surprised.